# Explanation of usage generic method with an expression

Tags: c#, generics, expression, func

I want to pass in a strongly types property to a method and use this propertyname as a string for mhy collection, so I found some code where I can pass my property strongly typed:

```
public static void Add<TObject, TProperty>(this NameValueCollection collection, Expression<Func<TObject, TProperty>> expression, string value)
{
    var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

    collection.Add(member.Member.Name, value);
}
```

This works and does what I want, but I was wondering how this exactly works. The part I am interested in is the generic arguments of the method (`Add<Tobject, TProperty>`) in combination with the `Func` expression. Can someone explain to me how this works? And why I can call this method like `collection.Add((MyObject m) => m.FullName, "Martijn")`? Why isn't it necessarly to use `Add<MyObject, ???>(m => m.FullName, "Martijn")`?

Update:
I now have my method refactored to this:

```
public static void Add<TObject>(this NameValueCollection collection, Expression<Func<TObject, string>> expression, string value)
{
    var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

    collection.Add(member.Member.Name, value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expression<T>` is an *expression tree* that has the signature of delegate-type `T`. Expression trees are complex, but basically: instead of being a delegate *that is* the operation, this is an object-model that *describes* the operation, and that can be inspected to see how it is composed.

Thus, an `Expression<Func<TObject,TProperty>>` is an expression-tree representing something that accepts `TObject` parameter and returns `TProperty` result.

As for why you don't need to tell it the `<MyObject, ???>` manually: that is generic type inference, and is normal. Given a generic method, say:

```
void Foo<T>(T bar);
```

You *can* call that as:

```
Foo<string>("abc");
```

but you can also use:

```
Foo("abc");
```

The compiler will then inspect the parameters to see if it can resolve all of the generic type parameters - in this case, the `"abc"` is a `string` and pins `T` to being a `string`. If it can resolve ***all*** of them, you don't need to specify them.

In your example, the `TObject` is pinned because your lambda explicitly takes a `MyObject`, via `(MyObject) m`, and the `TProperty` is pinned to (presumably) a `string`, because `m.FullName` (presumably) returns a `string`. Since all the generic type parameters have been resolved automatically you do not need to specify the `<...>` manually.

Note that generic type inference only applies to generic *methods* (via the parameters), not to generic *types*.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my post with a new method, but could you explain why I must use a Func and why I cannot use an Action? When I use an Action I get an error. Where is the return value (string) used in my method?

Comment: @Martijn you *can* use Action etc; but an Action does not have a return value; an Action version would only be usable for referring to void methods

Comment: but why do I need to use an Func in this case?